# "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly" error when building with the new Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After I've updated to the latest Xamarin.Forms (2.3.4.224) I keep getting build errors. anyone knows what this could be?

I suspect it might have to do with the new behavior changes they have introduced with the new version regarding Attached Properties (but I don't know that that means)

more info here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92455/xamarin-forms-2-3-4-224

and here is my build log

```
Error       The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXaml(RootNode rootNode, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.ParseXaml(Stream stream, TypeReference typeReference)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Shared
```

Comment: you should post your XAML

Comment: I have like 50 xaml files in my project and have no Idea which one has errors

Comment: I have the same problem.  How did you fix it?

Comment: couldn't fix it, so I rolled back to the previous version of Forms

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the same case, but I ran into the same problem.

I had different version of Forms installed. After I updated all nuget packages and deleted all obj and bin folders I was able to make a build without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your solution and close your Visual Studio 2017. The error will gone when you open it again.